# how to get a list out of list of lists in common lisp

Tags: list, split, common-lisp

I am new to common lisp and trying to get a list out of a splitted string.
For example:
*["4-No 16dia","6-No 20dia"]*
Now I want to collect only the third element like *["16","20"]*
I have got the splitting part correctly using:

```
(defun my-split (string &key (delimiterp #'delimiterp)
                    )
          (loop :for beg = (position-if-not delimiterp string)
            :then (position-if-not delimiterp string :start (1+ end)
                           )
            :for end = (and beg (position-if delimiterp string :start beg))
            :when beg :collect (subseq string beg end)
              :while end))
```

where :

```
(defun delimiterp (c) (position c " ,-:"))
```

but collecting only the third element into a list is the tricky part , I have tried:

```
(defparameter *list1*
  (loop for i in (cdr list)
     (append (parse-integer
                (nth 0
                     (my-split (nth 3 i)
                               :delimiterp #'delimiterp))))))
```

P.S: there are two list cz the example string is itself part of a list-of lists
Please help me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a regular expression, and I think I would do this largely irrespective of the language that I was using. Of course, some languages don't have regular expressions, but when they do it saves reinventing the wheel.

In Common Lisp, the regular expressions library is called Common Lisp - Practical Perl Compatible Regular Expressions, cl-ppcre. We load this with `(ql:quickload "cl-ppcre")`.

Then the numbers can be returned using `(ppcre:scan-to-strings "^(\\d*)-No (\\d*)dia$" x)`. The regular expression uses `\d` to pick out a digit, which in Lisp strings is written `\\d`. The asterisk says return zero or more digits. The parentheses in the regular expression is the bits that we are going to return, the numbers.

Doing this for a list of string is then just using `mapcar`.

```
(defparameter text-match "")
(defparameter text-numbers "")
(defparameter test-text '("4-No 16dia" "6-No 23dia"))


(defun extract-numbers (text)
  (setf (values text-match text-numbers)
    (ppcre:scan-to-strings "^(\\d*)-No (\\d*)dia$" text))
  text-numbers)

(defun extract-numbers-from-list (lst)
  (mapcar #'extract-numbers lst))

(extract-numbers-from-list test-text) ; => (#("4" "16") #("6" "23"))
```

**Edit: lexical bindings**

When I was writing the above, I was trying to get the regular expression right AND trying to get the lexical bindings right at the same time. Having only limited time I put the effort into getting the regular expressions right, and used dynamic variables and setf. OK, it got the job done, but we can do better.

The classical lexical binding system is `let`, syntax `(let ( (var1 val1) (var2 val2) ...) body)`. We can try `(let ((x 0)))`, which is valid Lisp code, but which doesn't do much. As soon as the lexical scope ends, the variable `x` is unbound. Attempting to access `x` causes an error.

We can return multiple values from many functions, such as `floor` or `scan-to-string`. We now have to bind these values to variables, using `(multiple-value-bind (variable-list) values)`. Most websites don't really do a good job of explaining this. Having bound the variables, I was getting errors about unbound variables. OK, it's worth just saying -

**`multiple-value-bind` binds variables lexically, just like `let`.**

The full syntax is `(multiple-value-bind (variable-list) values body)` and your code goes into the body section, just like `let`. Hence the above code becomes:

```
(defparameter test-text '("4-No 16dia" "6-No 23dia"))

(defun extract-numbers (text)
   (multiple-value-bind (text-match text-numbers)
     (ppcre:scan-to-strings "^(\\d*)-No (\\d*)dia$" text)
     text-numbers))

(defun extract-numbers-from-list (lst)
  (mapcar #'extract-numbers lst))

(extract-numbers-from-list test-text) ; => (#("4" "16") #("6" "23"))
```

Comment: Hey @Francis King , Thank you for your thoughtful reply. But I wanted to know if there is another way without feeding the format of the string like        
 _
"^(\\d*)-No (\\d*)dia$"
 _     .
Can I extract only the digits, cz we not sure if the spaces and comma will be in the right places

Comment: @Gayathri. The data will come as a list, within parentheses: `'("4-No 16dia" "6-No 23dia")`. If you start with a single string, with data separated by a comma, when you split the string on the comma you will be left with a list of strings and the comma will no longer be present. The regular expression is exactly the same format as Perl, so you can use `\\s` for a space, and `\\s*` for zero or more spaces.

Comment: if the list looks like ("4-12dia,4-10dia" 
"4-16dia,4-12dia" 
"4-12dia,4-10dia" 
"4-16dia,4-12dia" 
"4-20dia,4-12dia,2-16dia" 
"4-16dia,4-12dia,2-10dia" 
"4-20dia,4-12dia,2-10dia" 
"4-20dia,4-16dia,2-12dia" 
"4-20dia,6-12dia" 
"4-16dia,4-12dia,2-10dia" 
"4-20dia,8-10dia" 
"4-16dia,6-10dia" ) , is there any other alternative?

Comment: You could extend the regular expression to cover each string directly. You will have to try different things, but perhaps "(\\d+)\\s*-\\s*(\\d+)\\s*,\\s*(\\d+)\\s*-\\s*(\\d+)". Take a look at this: https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet

Answer (score 2):

Without dependencies, one could use:

```
(defun extract-nums (s)
  (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (parse-integer x :junk-allowed t)) 
          (ql-util:split-spaces s)))
```

And try it with:

```
(defparameter *s*  (list "4-No 16dia" "6-No 20dia"))
(mapcar #'extract-nums *s*)
;; => ((4 16) (6 20))
```

`parse-integer` with the setting `junk-allowed-p t` helps with extracting integer numbers from the string a lot.

But yes, in real-life I would also just use `cl-ppcre`, e.g.
Mainly the functions `cl-ppcre:split` and `cl-ppcre:scan-to-strings`.

```
(ql:quickload :cl-ppcre)

(defun extract-nums (s)
  (mapcar #'parse-integer (cl-ppcre:scan-to-strings "(\\d+)-No (\\d+)dia" s))
```

And from then on it is just

```
(second (map #'list (mapcar #'extract-nums *s*))
;; => (16 20)
```

Comment: Hey @Gwang-Jin Kim, is there another ql-util function which can split at comma and other special characters?

Comment: @Gayathri Unfortunately not. You have to use then `(cl-ppcre:split "[ .,;-]" your-string)`. - Actually, `cl-ppcre` and `alexandria` shouldn't count as depencies, because they contain useful missing functions.

Comment: @Gayathri Not from `ql-util` but `(asdf:split-string "a,b;c" :separator '(#\, #\;))` would give `("a" "b" "c")` - so you can give several one-character separators in a list.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, `cl-ppcre` also has `register-groups-bind` to do regex matching, binding, and converting in a single form:

```lisp
CL-USER> (cl-ppcre:register-groups-bind ((#'parse-integer no dia))
             ("(\\d+)-No (\\d+)dia" "4-No 16dia")
           (values no dia))
4
16
```